# Can BBW be used outside porn?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I heard a professional trader working at a hedge company say to his boss

```
"That stock is a real BBW, nice and bouncy".
```

***BBW*** actuall can be the abbreviation for many phrases, one of which is **big beautiful woman**.

(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BBW&utm_source=search-action)

And I can find BBW to be one category of porno sites.
Therefore,  I guess it originates from porn industry and may be a bad word on occasions that requires politeness.

Can I say something is a BBW when I want to describe it as nice and good? May it be offensive?  Will people relate what I say to porn?

Look at the samples I make. Are they good?

> - 1. That deal I've just made with the company is a real BBW. It'll bring a big profit.

> - 2. The mark Peter got in the exam is a real BBW, which makes him the most promising student.

> - 3. That kingdom, powerless in military but rich in natural resources, is such a BBW that every robber covets.

After reading different answers ,  I still think the third example I gave is quite okay. Any opinions ?

Comment: I would not use it in any of your 3 sentences. They don't really fit.   It *can* have other meanings https://www.acronymfinder.com/BBW.html

Comment: Any word you use like this is inherently reliant on your sexual preference. Porn categories are often very polarizing, with both strong proponents and opponents for every category. While you equate BBW to something good, others might equate it to something bad. Some people get off to feet licking, for others it's a turn-off.

Comment: BBW is frequently used outside of porn and I doubt it originated there, anyway. I think it originated in the fashion industry. BBW, however, does not mean 'nice and good' so do not use it in this sense and be particularly aware that people will generally assume that it says more about you than whatever it is you may be trying to describe.

Comment: A "friend" told me that the porn/dating-shorthand meaning he'd heard for BBW was _Big, Black Woman_ (used appreciatively; though "he" understands it might cause offence). "My friend" notes that [www.abbreviations.com/BBW](www.abbreviations.com/BBW) shows this meaning as the first of a number of alternatives, although the "What does BBW mean?" panel shows the _Big, beautiful woman_" version. Either way, it doesn't (to me) fit in any of your sentences.

Comment: It seems that it can also stand for "BIG BAD WOLF"

Comment: I doubt that the majority of US readers would understand what "BBW" means (assuming you can establish a meaning).

Comment: The primary rules when learning foreign languages are never try to swear and avoid using slang. At best you'll make a fool of yourself, at worst you'll end up with a bloody nose.

Comment: @TripeHound _Big, Black Woman_ was the first meaning that popped into my head, too. But that may be due to the mention of porn in the title and its similarity to BBC (which, in case you don’t know, refer to a certain similarly sized and coloured male feature). I would definitely **never, ever** use it as a generic word meaning ‘good’, under any circumstances. The term itself is potentially offensive and objectifying, and using it like that definitely would be.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure whether BBW i.e. Big Beautiful Women derives from the porn industry, it could well be, but nowadays it's used as an accolade for the larger woman. TV Tropes has this to say

> **[The Big Beautiful Woman](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigBeautifulWoman)**, or BBW for short, is an aversion of Hollywood's usual standards of size and beauty and is accompanied by Beauty Tropes or Attraction Tropes **which draw attention to her assets** with equal or greater Fanservice or Male Gaze than thinner women in the setting, and without being used as blatant irony. […]  Her weight may not even be (and, in most cases of the trope probably won't be) the basis of her beauty or attractiveness; **attention may instead be drawn to her beautiful eyes, feminine features or, more blatantly, her breasts or posterior** –but regardless, she is a knock-out.

To sum up, it's sexist, that's what it is. I couldn't give a hoot if it did derive from the porn industry, it's objectifying women. And in light of recent events, and all the [Weiners](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/05/anthony-weiner-psychologists), [Weinsteins](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/harvey-weinsteins-brother-bob-weinstein-accused-sexual-harassment/story?id=50541011), Clintons, Trumps, and [Cosbys](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/la-et-bill-cosby-timeline-htmlstory.html), I would avoid using the term among American women. Outside of the USA, I am doubtful how many would be familiar with its meaning.

It's not as if you're hard up for alternatives: *such a sweet deal*, *so outstanding*, *so exceptional*, or *such a jewel* the latter of which supports your robber metaphor so much better than BBW.

> 3. That kingdom, powerless in the military but rich in natural resources, is such a jewel that every robber covets it.

Comment: *{neutral, non-critical observation: "couldn't give a shoot" (in quotes) has zero hits in Google Books and about six hits on all of Google. I wonder if this can go towards supporting an initial  impression that this concatenation is not the most used, perhaps not historically idiomatic. I think how we use the North  American  euphemism 'shoot' deserves further research but I'm off to work.}*

Comment: @Clare I've always known it as "_couldn't give a hoot_". See [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+hoot).

Comment: @TripeHound Ahh, that's it. Perfect. I will edit, I *knew* Clare was also right, but I couldn't figure out where I was wrong (also very little free time today). Thank you so much!

Comment: *"To sum up, it's sexist, that's what it is (...) it's objectifying women."* __ totally right @Mari-lou A and that's the definitive answer to OP's question.